# How null pointer exception can be removed

Tags: android, exception

I am trying to find the signal strength of Wifi but I m getting a null pointer exception.
While fetching the network informatiopns like SSID etc. Can anyone suggest me a solution how to remove the null pointer exception.

```
enter code here:

public class MyReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{
    WifiManager wifi;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<ScanResult> results=wifi.getScanResults();
        ScanResult bestSignal=null;

        for(ScanResult result:results)
        {
            if(bestSignal==null || WifiManager.compareSignalLevel(bestSignal.level, result.level)<0)
                bestSignal=result;
        }

        String message=String.format("%s networks found. %s is the strongest", results.size(),bestSignal.SSID);
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d("Debug","onRecieve() message:" +message);
    }

}



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textStatus;
    WifiManager wifi;
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textStatus=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStatus);

        wifi=(WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        WifiInfo info=wifi.getConnectionInfo();
        textStatus.append("\n\nWifi Status: " +info.toString());

        List<WifiConfiguration> configs=wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for(WifiConfiguration config:configs)
        {
            textStatus.append("\n\n" +config.toString());
        }

        if(receiver==null)
                receiver = new MyReciever();

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        Log.d("TAG", "onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
            super.onStop();
    }
    }
```

Comment: 1. See the exception stacktrace in logcat. 2. Find the corresponding code line. 3. Look up the line in your code and figure out what is the  `null` that is dereferenced there. 4. Edit the question to contain the additional information at least from steps 1 and 2.

Comment: simple surround with try..catch(){} block.

Comment: 10-21 06:23:52.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 06:23:52.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1045): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wifi/com.example.wifi.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-21 06:23:52.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-21 06:23:52.851: E/AndroidRuntime(1045):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)

Answer (score 1):

Problem could be at `String message=String.format("%s networks found. %s is the strongest", results.size(),bestSignal.SSID);`

When there is no 'bestSignal' found, variable 'bestSignal' will be null and you are trying to execute `bestSignal.SSID` which might cause NPE.

Change you code like 
`if (bestSignal != null) {
String message=String.format("%s networks found. %s is the strongest", results.size(),bestSignal.SSID);
}`

Hope it helps :)